# How to show loading message while fetching data from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to display data into a textview. I use an asynctask to load data in the background, while loading, I want to show a loading message before the data loads into my textview.

But my loading data popup is not showing.(*i.e `doinBackground` method finish it works immediately*) and the user sees empty textviews and only after sometime that Firebase data loads.

How to prevent this and show process dialog until my textview get loaded with Firebase data?

```
here is my code
<pre>
<code>
public class LastPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView title, author, article;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_last_page);


        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_page_title);
        author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_page_author);
        article = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_page_article);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        new LoadFirebaseData().execute();


    }

    private class LoadFirebaseData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
    {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(LastPage.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            try {
                Dialog.setMessage("Doing something...");
                Dialog.show();
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
        {

            if(result==0)
            {
                //do some thing
            }
            // after completed finished the progressbar
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

            mDatabase.child("version_1_5").child("title").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String temp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    title.setText(temp);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            mDatabase.child("version_1_5").child("author").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String temp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    author.setText(temp);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            mDatabase.child("version_1_5").child("article").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String temp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    article.setText(temp);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            return 0;
        }


    }
}


</code>
</pre>
```

JSON tree structure:

```
Root
    Version_1_5
        Title:TitleValue
        Author:AuthorValue
        Article:ArticleValue
```

Comment: Please share your json tree

Comment: in my json tree it have 3 childnodes like this  root/version_1_5/title:valueOfTitle, root/version_1_5/aticle:valueOfArticle, root/version_1_5/author:valueOfAuthor

Answer (score 6):

you should use addListenerForSingleValueEvent to fetch the data from the node once not for the every single node

```
private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(LastPage.this);
Dialog.setMessage("Doing something...");
Dialog.show();
mDatabase.child("version_1_5").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot Snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(Snapshot.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Title")){
                String temp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                title.setText(temp);
            }
            else if(Snapshot.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Author")){
                String temp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                author.setText(temp);
            }
            else if(Snapshot.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Article")){
                 String temp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                article.setText(temp);
            }
        }
        Dialog.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: yes I changed code, but still progress dialog issue not solved. My main issue is to show progress dialog until data get loaded into textviews

Comment: hello your code is fine, but Dialog not showing and it get dismiss immediately, when I attached debugger on Dialog.hide I saw  doing something Dialog  is running. I think main reason behind this is datasnapshot.getvalue() is working in async task so all other statement executes immediately and that's why Dialog.hide also get executed, currently I am using Thread.sleep() to show dialog running. I like hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was fetching data from firebase, so I logged the Code and saw that the problem is

> The onPostExecute() code is run before the data from Firebase has  been loaded to the app.

So I thought of an hack and instead of calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on `onPostExecute()` I called it in the `doInBackground()` method after the data from Firebase has been loaded and also hid the progress bar in the same methond like this -

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        DataBaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("child").child("something");
            DataBaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //Code for Fetching data from firebase

                    }
                    categoryDetailsFragmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //categoryDetailsFragmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As by default visibility of progressbar is **true** in layout file ,so we only need to set it to **false**. You only need do this line in your layout file as follows.
Suppose this is the simplest progressbar initialization.

```
<ProgressBar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Here the main thing is  `android:visibility="invisible".`
Hope it helps many & save their time.