# Using a progress bar

Tags: android

How do i use a progress bar in this kind of scenario?? I want a progress bar to show once the register button is clicked and if registration is successful, i also want to give a success massage to the user:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sme);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    bizname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bizname);
    location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);
    biztype = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.biztype);
    pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating firebase object
            **progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**
            final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://mcn-africa.firebaseio.com/");

            //Getting values to store
            String Username = bizname.getText().toString();
            String Name = biztype.getText().toString();
            String Id = pin.getText().toString();
            String Location = location.getText().toString();

            Members members = new Members();
            members.setUsername(Username);
            members.setLocation(Location);
            members.setName(Name);
            members.setId(Id);



            Firebase newRef = ref.child("SMEs").push();


            newRef.setValue(members);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
}
```

}
any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use as a green and red bar that shows whether the login is successful or not.

Comment: can you intergrate that in my code please....I just need to show the user that registration is in progress and if complete?? tell them success you have registered

Answer (score 0):

You cant show the progress up on your signup process. The only thing you can do is give a progress loader on the signup process or you have to create a manual static progress update while calling the signup.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AsynTask` to connect to firebase so as to validate the credentials.
Make the `ProgressBar` visible in the `onPreExecute()` method.
Set the visibility of the `ProgressBar` to `GONE` in the `OnPostExecute()` method.
You can then use an `AlertDialog` to let the user know that the registration was successful.

Comment: if you dont mind, just show me in a code example, it is not that easy for me like it is for you...i am a new programmer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 //defining firebaseauth object
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initializing firebase auth object
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //initializing views
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);  //progress dialog

    //attaching listener to button
    buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void registerUser(){

    //getting email and password from edit texts
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //checking if email and passwords are empty
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    //if the email and password are not empty
    //displaying a progress dialog

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    //creating a new user
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

}
```

See [Here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-firebase-tutorial-1/)

for detail implementation

Comment: good one, but i am only adding data to firebase no registration...i want the progress bar to show while adding data to firebase

Comment: it is the same concept....see this also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620872/how-to-show-loading-message-while-fetching-data-from-firebase-database